# How to send SOL through a wallet that has become the token address of a token?

Tags: spl-token, transaction

I have all the privatekey and phrase key. i try to send the sol using phantom and solflare but i got the error "Transaction simulation failed: this account may not be used to pay transaction fees solana" can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

That's unlikely, only System Program accounts have Private Keys, thus, they are on curve. For example this is a token account and as you can see in More Info it says isOnCurve=false: https://solscan.io/account/6kiE7g1VNYPauinqwSZvNZehTXbCiMpYZb1sujxgAYtt

Which is the public key of your wallet that is stuck?

Comment: SWANaZUGxF82KyVsbxeeNsMaVECtimze5VyCdywkvkH

i using this wallet to be a token mint address

Comment: The owner of that Account is the Token Program, not the system program.

Comment: Note that it is incorrect that only system program accounts have private keys. Program-derived addresses do not have private keys, but they can be accounts owned by any program, including the system program.

Answer (score 0):

Only accounts owned by the system program may be used as fee payers for transactions, so when you provide a token mint as the fee payer, the transaction will fail.

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to close mints in SPL Token to reset the account to the system program, so you'll need to use another account with SOL to pay for transactions.